# Updating value inside of json file

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, object, updates

Is it possible to update a value inside of `json` file when a button is click? For example is this:

```
{
    "caught": "0",
    "id": 1,
    "location": "River",
    "north": "Nov ~ Mar",
    "price": 900,
    "south": "May ~ Sept",
    "tod": "All day"
},
{
    "caught": "0",
    "id": 2,
    "location": "Sea",
    "north": "Nov ~ Mar",
    "price": "2,500",
    "south": "May ~ Sept",
    "tod": "4pm - 9am"
}
```

I want to change the caught from 0 to 1 with the id of 1. is it possible? I'm using javascript by the way.

Comment: What do you plan to do with the result when you change it?

Comment: Your question is too broad. **What is the problem?** Reading the JSON? Parsing the JSON? Editing the resulting data structure? Converting back to JSON? Writing the JSON to a file? **Where is the code running?** It sounds like you are talking about JS running in a browser via a `<script>` element, but you haven't been explicit. **Where is the file** relative to wherever the JS is running? On a web server? On the visitor's hard disk?

Comment: Changing contents of a JSON file is not possible with client side JS or jQuery

Comment: Okay for example, i wanna change the value of location from "river" to "sea" with an id of 1

Comment: @JayRhick — That example addresses none of the questions about your problem that anyone has asked in the comments.

Comment: Also, please read the formatting help next to the question editor. It generally helps if your code is readable rather then squished into a single line

Comment: Oh, and your JSON is invalid (or your example is incomplete)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible.

1. First, make sure your button has an ID, like so: `<button id="myButton"` />
2. Attach an event listener for the "click" event:

```
const element = document.getElementById('myButton');
button.addEventListener('click', (event) => modifyObject());
```

3. Then you can write your "modifyObject" function. This will map your array of elements and if the given item has a specific ID, it will return a different result. It should look like the following:

```
arr.map(x => {
    if (x.id === 1) {
         return {
             ...x,
             caught: 1
         };
    }
    return x;
});
```

I was using the spread operator (...) which effectively expands an iterable object.

Comment: You missed out reading the file, parsing the JSON, converting back to JSON, and saving the JSON.